# Impress Pages Themes

Tags: php, impresspages

I am using Impress Pages and currently using the theme "Air."  At the top of the page, how do I move the picture to the center of the page.  Secondly, below the picture, I have added text; how do I increase the font size?  Thirdly, is there a way to change the white color in the center box to another color?

Comment: I don't know anything about impress pages. But if you provide any links to a demo page, or provide some details about this "impress pages", then we could try to help you out, at least. Are you trying to make these modifications by editing html code? Or there are some functionalities in the admin panel about these needs of yours?

Comment: http://communitychapelbaptistchurch.org/ImpressPages/  On this particular page, is there a way to increase the size of font where the pics are and can I decrease the font size at the top of the page?  Also, how do I move the pics to be in the center and is it possible to add color to the area that is white?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you can modify in templates existing CSS file or you can create new one and include it in template header.

Comment: I am somewhat new to building a website but I have a desire to learn...could you please explain to me how to modify in templates existing CSS file?  Also, is there a way to d/l a theme from another source to Impress Pages?

Answer (score 0):

Before anyone else down votes your question, I have some suggestions which I hope you'll take seriously. First of all, as I understand from your questions, you have very limited knowledge about [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp), [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) and probably none about [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp). Follow these links (many people may disagree with my suggestion on w3schools, but that site is the best place for beginner - as I began my journey with that site - in my opinion. Feel free to suggest more) and have some study first. It'll take some days considering how much time you'll invest on that study. Then you'll have a general understanding of how things work and will be able to ask specific questions about your problems.

Building web sites may at first seems an easy work. But as you begin learning stuff you'll realize that to create some serious stuff, takes many years of practise. So, after following those links and having some general idea about how html and css works, you can go install a [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/) or [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) site and use some free stuff which are even used by the experienced developers to save time on development simple sites with simple requirements.

Also, using StackOverflow, you have some [rules / recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to follow. If you take a moment and follow them, your questions will be much appreciated and you'll be able to benefit from other people's experiences.

I am just trying to help here, as I was (and everyone in this community) a beginner once.

Good luck on your journey!

Answer (score 0):

Down and dirty method in the admin panel (while figuring out later how to modify code in ImpressPages):

1. Drag the image icon to the content area, and insert the image.
2. Drag another image icon to the left of the new image, but do not insert an image. Drag a second one to the right of the new image...using both of these as placeholders. ImpressPages automatically divides the available space, leaving the image centered.